# iPhone not syncing old iCloud photos

Tags: iphone, photos.app, icloud

Our iPhone doesn't sync with old iCloud photos.  It only syncs the past 5 years or so.  How can you force a full sync?   My devices have a lot of space I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the actual space settings on your phone. iCloud can show how much space might be needed.

[image: settings app, iCloud, iCloud storage]

Also, I would turn save space option to see if that makes the device more willing to sync down at least all the thumbnails needed.

[image: optimize photo storage from iCloud]
[image: Settings app, general, about showing space available]